# How to disable Microsoft Edge from the start menu in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, window, microsoft-edge

I used to be able to disable microsoft edge when you click on it from the [start menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J4Nv.png)   and no pop-up browser will appear. Basically, I did it by renaming my Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe directory in my C:\Windows\SystemApps. Now after I upgraded my OS to windows 10 22H2. Renaming the directory does not work anymore. Is there any other ways to do this? or does any expert knows why it does not work anymore?

Comment: Probably not but try Autoruns (SysInternals) and see if you can stop Edge with Autoruns.

Comment: @John - The user is trying to avoid the browser being listed in the start menu not prevent it from automatically starting at login. If the author is trying to do that then it’s not evident by their question

Comment: Yes I understand but my thinking was to disable Edge from running to see if that might help.

Comment: The start menu link for edge is in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ `. Just change the target to something else in the link properties, or remove it entirely?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I've removed everything in the programs folder and the edge browser is still existing inside the start menu as it is tied to the system files

Comment: ah ok, that is a bit strange. It looks like you can change the target though by recreating the icon named "Microsoft Edge" > right click > properties > change target and folder to a different program path like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`. Then clicking "Microsoft Edge" in the start menu will open that instead.